# How to change between 2 screens on-Button-Click

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I am building a web-app for the wating room. Most of the time there will be a video shown like " earth-tv" whatever. If the doctors assistance is calling a patient to go to the doctor it should appear on the screen and make the video disappear for a moment. I know that it has to be done by an ButtonClick-Event but i don't know how.

```
      return (
      <div className="maincontent">
    <div className="topbar">
    <button className="testbutton" onClick={() => this.test()}>
        TEST
      </button>
      <div className="topbarlabel">
        <label className="label15">{this.state.praxisname}</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div className="maindiv">
      <video className="videoplayer"  src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4"controls autostart autoPlay muted
        controls={['PlayPause', 'Seek', 'Time', 'Volume', 'Fullscreen']}
        poster="http://sourceposter.jpg">
      </video>
      {/* Patientenaufruf */}
      {Object.keys(patient).length > 0 && (
        <div className="patientenaufruf blink">
          <label className="label30 item">
            {patient.titel} {patient.vorname} {patient.nachname}
          </label>
          <label className="label30 item">bitte in</label>
          <label className="label30 item">{patient.raum}</label>
        </div>
      )}
```

Comment: Some questions:

1. Is the `patient` object being passed in as a prop to this component? From Redux, or another way?

2. Who will be changing the `patient` object? Is it coming from someone using this app? Someone using another app? A server passing that information automatically from a queue?

Comment: @Idtcoop 1. Yes exactly. 2. The object will be changed by the doctors assistance, she will fire the event with a buttonClick.

Comment: Do you have any Redux code (actions, reducers, etc.) set up for handing patient objects? If so, can you post it?